# #C Razor Join Data LINQ

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

Attempting to display a table with a join on the `Rating`
 to the `ID` within the `Ratings` table. I'm hitting an issue with the `join` within my statement.

```
var Movie = from u in _context.Movie
                                 join g in _context.Ratings
                                 on u.Rating equals g.ID
                                 select (a => new List
                                 {
                                     Ratings = u.Rating,
                                     MovieRating = g.MovieRating

                         });


            Movie = await Movie.ToListAsync();
```

The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: `on u.Rating equals g.ID` doesn't looks correct to me at all

Comment: what are the types of Movie.Rating and Rating.ID?

Comment: Also please follow good naming conventions for your properties. Having RatingID in Movie entity is more appropriate than just 'Rating'

Comment: `Movie.Rating` is a `int` field and `Rating.ID` is also `Int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some weird syntax like (a => new List { ... Not sure where you are going with that.
Do you have a class named List? are you trying to get a List? Why is "a" in there...since it is not referenced anywhere. You also try to change the type of the Movie variable in your code, the var keyword doesn't work that way. On the first line, you assign a IQueryable< T> to it and later on you try to assign a List< T> to it.

try something like this:

```
var movieQuery = from u in _context.Movie
                 join g in _context.Ratings on u.Rating equals g.ID
                 select new
                 {
                     Ratings = u.Rating,
                     MovieRating = g.MovieRating
                 };
var movies = await movieQuery.ToListAsync(); // query will be executed here
```

The example code above uses an anonymous class as result so movies will be of type List< T> where T is an anonymous class, if you do have a class called List (for some reason) representing a single result item, then use

```
select new List { ...
```

instead of

```
select new { ...
```

and if you don't wanna split the query / actual list into 2 variables, you can do something like:

```
var movies = await (from u in _context.Movie
             join g in _context.Ratings on u.Rating equals g.ID
             select new
             {
                Ratings = u.Rating,
                MovieRating = g.MovieRating
             }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hi, I've just been trying to get anything working using snippets from the net. I have the following `public List<Movie> Movie { get;set; }`  then using your code when I changed up a little `var Movie = await (from m in _context.Movie
                                join r in _context.Ratings on m.Rating equals r.ID.ToString()
                                select new
                                {
                                    m.Title,
                                    r.MovieRating


                                }).ToListAsync() ;`

Comment: how do I then reference this within the html page. `@foreach (var item in Model.Movie) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)`

Comment: well u need to declare `@model ClassNameHere` at the top of your cshtml file, if you use anonymous class for a model, the easiest way is to use `@model dynamic`.  In your controller you have to pass the model (your list of movies) to the view. so if u only have the movies you can do `var Movies = await ...` and then `return View(Movies)` --> since ur model is of type List< T> where T is anonymous class, you would put `@model List<dynamic>` on top of ur cshtml page and then in the page itself: `@foreach(var movie in Model) { <tr><td>@movie.Title</td><td>@movie.MovieRating</td></tr> }`